# How to use quick replies (FB) in a python chatbot?

Tags: python, facebook, chatbot

I'm building a Facebook Messenger bot in Python and my script for quick replies is not working event though I already know how to send simple text messages and generic templates. This is my code so far:

## This one works:

```
text = {
    "recipient": {
        "id": user_id
    },
    "message": {
        "text": "some text"
    }
}
```

## This one doesn't:

```
question = {
    "recipient": {
        "id": user_id
    },
    "message": {
        "quick_replies": [{
            "content_type": "location"
            # "title": "RED",
            # "text": "red",
            # "payload": "red"
         }]
    }
}
```

## POST for both:

```
headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}
requests.post('url', data = json.dumps(text), headers=headers)
requests.post('url', data = json.dumps(question), headers=headers)
```

In the example, title, text and payload are commented since I'm trying to make the script work with something as basic as location... but I keep receiving a response 400 for 'question'; 'text' works just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix <Response \[400\]> while make a POST in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257168/how-to-fix-response-400-while-make-a-post-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

`“text”: “some string”` or `”attachment”: []` is **required** when using quick replies.

Check the fields required in the [FB Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is putting "text" key alongside "quick_replies"; otherwise - inside list/dict "quick_replies" as mentioned in FB Docs (for JavaScript) -  it won't work:

```
question = {
    "recipient": {
        "id": user_id
    },
    "message": {
        "text": "<THIS_IS_WHERE_THE_ACTUAL_TEXT_GOES>,
        "quick_replies": [{
            "content_type": "text"
            "title": "Option 1",
            "payload": "option1"
         }]
    }
}
```